# Создание дубликатов на основе значения количества в поле

Tags: oracle, plsql, table

Существует таблица `LIBRARY` книг вида

```
|id_name | NAME |COUNT |AUTHOR |
------------------------------
|1593    |Лирика|3     |ПУШКИН |
|65096   |Береза|2     |ЕСЕНИН |
```

необходимо разбить данную таблицу в новую таблицу `NEW_LIBRARY` по правилу, сколько `COUNT`, столько строк

```
|id_book | id_name |NAME   |AUTHOR |
------------------------------------
|1       |1593     |Лирика |ПУШКИН |
|2       |1593     |Лирика |ПУШКИН |
|3       |1593     |Лирика |ПУШКИН |
|4       |65096    |Береза |ЕСЕНИН |
|5       |65096    |Береза |ЕСЕНИН |
```

Comment: *Разбиение строки на её подстроки* Ну вообще-то Вам нужно дублирование записей. Никакого разбиения тут нет и в помине..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычный рекурсивный CTE:

```sql
WITH cte (id_name, NAME, "COUNT", AUTHOR) AS (
  SELECT id_name, NAME, "COUNT" - 1, AUTHOR
  FROM LIBRARY
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id_name, NAME, "COUNT" - 1, AUTHOR
  FROM cte
  WHERE "COUNT" > 0
)
SELECT id_name, NAME, AUTHOR
FROM cte;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/oXfP5p1z

Ну или то же самое, но с использованием специфично Ораклового CONNECT BY.

Думаю, преобразовать его в соответствующий INSERT не составит проблемы.. равно как и добавить ORDER BY, если нужен.